# NHibernate 3 session state after rollback()

Tags: nhibernate, session, transactions, rollback

I have a problem.

```
using (var tran = repository.Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        repository.Save(entity);
        tran.Comit();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    }    
}

using (var tran = repository.Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        repository.GetById(id);
        tran.Comit();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    }    
}
```

When I try to get an entity by ID after exception and `tran.rollback()` in the first `using` block, I get an update exception. So NHibernate is trying to update the entity from the first `using` block in the second `using` block.

Why? I did the `tran.Rollback()`. Must I do `Session.Clear()`, too?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to Hibernate's API, when a Hibernate Session throws an exception, you *must* close the Session and create a new one. Also, when you roll back a Hibernate transaction, you must not later commit it or flush the Session - you *must* start over in a new Session.

In particular (and this is an implementation detail so don't rely on it), after a rollback, the Hibernate Session still has entities created/modified since the transaction began - Hibernate doesn't go through your entities and revert all changes you made. Therefore, if you roll back the transaction and then flush the Session, **Hibernate will commit entity changes that you thought you rolled back**. If you are going to play with fire by trying to hack around this behavior (such as by clearing the Session), beware. It's best to just start over with a new Session.

Comment: Ok, but my session is contextual managed by structuremap ioc, and is per wcf call. If I dispose the session then I will have errors elsewhere.

Comment: What exceptions are you getting? Can you try to prevent them? Can you post them here?

Comment: I am getting GenericAdoException , because I am trying to insert a duplicate value, that must be unique. But that is not the point. I need to know what is the best practice. Until now I have exception handling like the one above. But now, I am seeing that this will not be enough.

Comment: I can not predict every exception that can happen, I need to have exception handling, and I need to know what must I do so I dont get invalid data in db.

Comment: @Luka since you are using a session-per-call it would make sense to have a transaction-per-call (transaction-per-session). This will serve the contextual unit-of-work where each call has no potential side-effects: if a query fails in a call, all db operations that were done in the call will be rollbacked.

Comment: I've spent hours trying to figure out why my rollback wasn't rolling back. Thanks.