# nHibernate: Fails to rollback complete operation

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, fluent-nhibernate

We have a userobject split between two tables, a person table and user table.

```
public UserMap() 
{
   Table("Person");
   Id(x => x.PersonId, "PersonId");
   Map(x => x.Name, "Name");

   Join("User", s => {
      s.Fetch.Join();
      s.KeyColumn("PersonId");
      s.Map(x => x.Username, "Username");
      s.Map(x => x.Password, "Password");
   });
}
```

When doing a insert, nHibernate will first insert `Name` into the `Person` table, and then `Username` and `Password` into the `User` table.

**The problem arise when the insertion into the `User`-table fails (like trying to insert a user with a username that is already taken). The transaction fails, but the insertion into the `Person` table is not rolled back.**

```
    public User Save(User user)
    {
        var session = SessionHelper.GetCurrent();
        using (var dbTransaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                session.SaveOrUpdate(user);
                dbTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                dbTransaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }                
        }

        return user;
    }
```

Our SessionFactory is also set up with Fluent NHibernate

```
    public ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        return Fluently.Configure().Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(c => c.Is(connectionString))
                                             .Provider<OracleDriverConnectionProvider>()
                                             .Driver<OracleDataClientDriver>()
                                             .ShowSql)
                                             .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>())
                                             .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

I have put the logfile from a failing session [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/vegar/5458141). The `User` entity is a little more complex in real life, and there are some authentication stuff going on, so the log file want match 1:1 with the painted picture...

Comment: From the accepted answer, it looks like this question was indeed a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4368421/1178314), having better answer. [This other one](/q/25902317/1178314) is related (and newer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a similar problem was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4368621/2323504). NHibernate will not revert you changes in the session when you rollback your transaction, i.e if you flush your session after the rollback, you will experience the problems you describe. To ensure no changes in your entities, when you rollback, you have to also close the session.

Answer (score 0):

Add User object in Person Object and Save Person Object only. Use Cascade.All() in Mapping file. or Second option is use TransactionScope.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of closing the session, you can use session.Clear() after you have roleld back the transaction, which will remove all pending writes and make session as good as new. 
That did the trick for my application.

Comment: -1. You have no cleanup guarantee. As stated by [documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-endingsession-commit): "If you rollback the transaction you should immediately close and discard the current session to ensure that NHibernate's internal state is consistent.". Using any trick contradicting documentation is the path to unexpected failures.